# method post/get/delete/put not found on phpstorm using lumen

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm-2017.2, lumen-5.4

I already tried adding this composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper.

then I install the laravel plugin using the plugin on the ide.

next I add this to my composer.json

```
"post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
```

but still my routes show warnings.

[image]

Comment: try to invalidate caches and restart (in the File menu).

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I just did it but still have the same issue